# how to insert unique data for the specific member

Tags: php, mysql

This is my table in MYSQL and I want to insert unique record for contacted_member_id for the member_id, Means member_id=1 can have multiple record but it should be unique, and i am inserting by the PHP page, but coding is not working  properly.

```
    create table contact_viewed(
    contact_viewed_id int(11) not null auto_increment,
    contacted_member_id int (11) not null,
    member_id int(11) not null,
    primary key(contact_viewed_id)
    );
```

My php file is shown below

```
 <?php
    include_once 'dbconfig.php';
    if (! $user->is_loggedin ()) {
    $user->redirect ( 'login.php' );
    }
    $m_id = $_SESSION ['user_session'];
    $stmt = $DB_con->prepare ( "SELECT * FROM member WHERE member_id=:member_id" );
    $stmt->execute ( array (
    ":member_id" => $m_id 
    ) );
    $userRow = $stmt->fetch ( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
    ?>


    <?php
    $stmt7 = $DB_con->prepare ( "SELECT * FROM contact_viewed WHERE member_id=:member_id" );
    $stmt7->bindParam ( ":member_id", $m_id );
    $stmt7->execute ();
    $row2 = $stmt7->fetchAll ();
    if ($stmt7->rowCount () > 0) {
    foreach ( $row2 as $data ) {
     if ($data ['member_id'] == $m_id) {enter code here
     if($data ['contacted_member_id'] == $_GET['id']){
         echo "do nothing1";
     }
     else{
         $stmt6 = $DB_con->prepare ( "INSERT INTO contact_viewed(contacted_member_id,member_id) VALUES(:contacted_member_id,:member_id)" );
         $stmt6->bindParam ( ":contacted_member_id", $_GET ['id'] );
         $stmt6->bindParam ( ":member_id", $m_id );
         $stmt6->execute ();
         echo "hello";
     }
     } 
    } 
    }
    else{
    $stmt6 = $DB_con->prepare ( "INSERT INTO contact_viewed(contacted_member_id,member_id) VALUES(:contacted_member_id,:member_id)" );
    $stmt6->bindParam ( ":contacted_member_id", $_GET ['id'] );
    $stmt6->bindParam ( ":member_id", $m_id );
    $stmt6->execute ();
    $available_contact = $userRow ['available_contact'];
    $available_contact = $available_contact - 1;
    $stmt5 = $DB_con->prepare ( "UPDATE member SET available_contact=:available_contact WHERE member_id=:member_id" );
    $stmt5->bindParam ( ":available_contact", $available_contact );
    $stmt5->bindParam ( ":member_id", $m_id );
    $stmt5->execute ();
    echo "ok ok";
    }
    ?>
    <?php
    require 'script.php';
    ?>

    <!-- close all connection at the end of the page -->

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>

    <?php
    require 'css.php';
    ?>

    <?php
    require 'config.php';
    ?>

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme-inner.css" />
   </head>
   <body>
    <?php
    require 'nav.php';
    ?>

    <div align="center">
    <h1>Contact Detail</h1>
    </div>

    <section class="full-width-inner">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="margin: 0 auto;">
     <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12" style="margin: 0 auto;">
     <h2 class="article-title">Profile</h2>
     <div class="row">
         <?php require 'leftNav.php';?>

    <?php

    if (isset ( $_GET ['id'] )) {
    $search = trim ( $_GET ['id'] );
    $result = mysqli_query ( $conn, "select * from member where member_id like '%" . $search . "%' Limit 1" );
    $rows = mysqli_num_rows ( $result );
    if ($rows) {
    while ( $post = mysqli_fetch_assoc ( $result ) ) {
     ?>




     <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
         <div class="panel panel-info light-pink">
          <div class="panel-heading action-box">
          <div class="panel-caption">
              <h3 class="panel-title"><?php print($post['member_name']); ?></h3>
          </div>
          <!-- panel-caption -->
          <div class="panel-tools">
              <a href="view_profiles_others.php?id=<?php echo $search ?>"
              class="btn btn-white-outline btn-xsmall">View Member Profile</a>
          </div>
          <!-- panel-tools -->

          <div class="panel-tools">
              <a href="view_contact.php?id=<?php echo $search ?>"
              class="btn btn-white-outline btn-xsmall">View Contact Deatil</a>
          </div>
          <!-- panel-tools -->
          </div>
          <!-- panel panel-info light-pink -->
          <div class="panel-body">

          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3">
              <a href="view_contact.php?id=<?php echo $search;?>"><img
               alt="Image Not Available"
               src="<?php echo $post['upload_image_path'];?>"
               class="thumbnail" /></a>
              </div>
              <!-- col-md-4 col-lg-3 -->
              <div class="col-md-8 ">
              <div class="profile-sumup">

               <div class="row">
               <table class="table table-condensed table-user-information">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">Name</td>
                    <td><span>:</span> <?php echo $post['member_name'];?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">Date Of Birth</td>
                    <td><span>:</span> <?php echo $post['day'];?>/<?php echo $post['month'];?>/<?php echo $post['year'];?></td>
                </tr>
                    <?php
     $year = $userRow ['year'];
     $y = date ( "Y" );
     $age = $y - $year;
     ?>
                    <tr>
                    <td class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">Age</td>
                    <td><span>:</span> <?php echo $age;?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">Email</td>
                    <td><span>:</span> <?php echo $post['email'];?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">Country</td>
                    <td><span>:</span> <?php echo $post['country'];?></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">Residing State</td>
                    <td><span>:</span> <?php echo $post['residing_state'];?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">City</td>
                    <td><span>:</span> <?php echo $post['city'];?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">Contact Address</td>
                    <td><span>:</span> <?php echo $post['contact_address'];?></td>
                </tr>

         <tr>
          <td class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">Primary Mobile Number</td>
           <td><span>:</span> <?php echo $post['primary_mobile_number'];?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">Alternate Mobile Number</td>
                    <td><span>:</span> <?php echo $post['alternate_mobile_number'];?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">Citizenship</td>
                    <td><span>:</span> <?php echo $post['citizenship'];?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">Residing Status</td>
                    <td><span>:</span> <?php echo $post['residing_status'];?>  </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
               </table>
               <!-- table -->
               </div>
               <!-- /row -->
              </div>
              <!-- profile-sumup -->



              </div>
              <!-- col-md-8 -->

          </div>
          <!-- row -->

          </div>
          <!-- panel-body -->
         </div>
         <!-- col-sm-8 col-md-9 col-lg-9 -->

     <?php
    }
    } else {

    ?>
     <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
          <div class="panel panel-info light-pink">
          <div class="panel-heading action-box">
              <div class="panel-caption">
     <h3 class="panel-title"><?php echo "No Record Found In The  Database!"?></h3>
              </div>
              <!-- panel-caption -->
          </div>
          <!-- panel-heading action-box -->
          </div>
          <!-- panel panel-info light-pink -->



         </div>
         <!-- col-sm-8 col-md-9 col-lg-9 -->
              <?php
     }
     }

     ?>

         </div>
         <!-- row -->
     </div>
     <!-- col-lg-12 col-md-12 -->
     </div>
     <!-- row -->
     </div>
      <!-- container -->

     </section>
     <!-- full-width-inner -->

     </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: That's a big slab of code for "not working properly". What does that mean?

Comment: Do you want to allow the same contacted_member_id to be associated with multiple different member_id? If yes then your primary key will have to contain those two columns (or use autoincrementing primary and add unique key with those) - each pair is unique, but each column can contain repeated values paired with a different one each time. If this is just such [junction table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) then the autoincrementing column should not be needed at all.

Comment: @AndySavage thanks for your response,it is working but not inserting as i want...

Comment: @ArifKhan thats almost as helpful.. We have no crystal ball to see what you want. You need to specify what you want it to do and what it is doing instead, show some examples etc. Help us help you.